# Map function return type based on argument enum

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type the return type of a generic factory function based on the argument.

The argument of the generic factory function is of type enum "MType".

What I basically want to achieve is this:

```js
interface Q {}
interface S {}

enum MType {
    Q = 'q',
    V = 'v',
}

const q = factory(MType.Q); // q is of type Q
const s = factory(MType.S); // s is of type S
```

This is what I have so far:

```js
enum MType {
    Q = 'q',
    V = 'v',
}

interface Q {}
interface V {}

type FactoryReturnType<T extends MType> = 
    T extends MType.Q 
        ? Q 
        : T extends MType.V 
            ? V 
            : never;

function factoryQ(): Q {
    return {};
}
function factoryV(): V {
    return {};
}

function factory<T extends MType>(type: T): FactoryReturnType<T> {
    type FactoryMap = Record<MType, () => FactoryReturnType<MType>>

    const factoryMap: FactoryMap = {
        [MType.Q]: factoryQ,
        [MType.V]: factoryV,
    }

    return factoryMap[type]();
}

const q = factory(MType.Q); // q should be of type Q
```

This doesn't work though. The problem lies with the declared return type of the factory method. I get the message:

```
Type 'Q | V' is not assignable to type 'FactoryReturnType<T>'.
  Type 'Q' is not assignable to type 'FactoryReturnType<T>'.
```

Unfortunately I don't understand why this is wrong. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this, so I can understand :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this one works, but it works:

```
interface FactoryReturnMap {
  [MType.Q]: Q,
  [MType.V]: V,
}

function factory<T extends MType>(type: T): FactoryReturnMap[T] {
  // type FactoryMap = Record<MType, () => FactoryReturnMap[MType]>

  const factoryMap = {
    [MType.Q]: factoryQ,
    [MType.V]: factoryV,
  }

  return factoryMap[type]();
}
```

Replace `FactoryReturnType` with `FactoryReturnMap` and everything will be fine.
Commented `FactoryMap` seems not required and it still works if un-commented it.

Comment: This works because of [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109); you might want to read that and include it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of [Jerryh001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76612683/669073) works indeed, but what also seem to work is using method overloading.

```js
function factory<T extends MType>(type: T): FactoryReturnType<T>;
function factory<T extends MType>(type: T) {
    type FactoryMap = Record<MType, () => FactoryReturnType<MType>>

    const factoryMap: FactoryMap = {
        [MType.Q]: factoryQ,
        [MType.V]: factoryV,
    }

    return factoryMap[type]();
}

const i = factory(MType.V); // i is now correctly inferred as V
```